# Where does the android simulator save the file?

Tags: android, cordova, emulation

where does the cordova.file.dataDirectory save the file?
i know it is in the persistent and private data storage.It is not found in the project but it is in the emulator.
How can i find it?

Comment: I tried to use DDMS in the open perspective>other>DDMS, yet i could not find it

Comment: Are you kidding?! Why do you keep deleting your questions, where you have accepted the answers given to you? What is wrong with you? Very asshole-ish behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C:\Users\"User name"\ .android\adv There are images of all types of storage used by emulator.

Comment: i mean the file.(e.g i save an image)

Comment: The filea, e.g. image as you said, are stores inside android devce system images, which locations by default is where I pointed. Maybe you have to find a way to read these images.

Comment: thnk you bro. what i understand it is stored within the app?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get your question. What did you mean by "stored within the app"?

Comment: The app save a file into the app

Comment: Beware. fsd deletes questions he gets answers to.